# what are the various ways to define function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Which is is the  best way to define a function in javascript . how to define a function  using ':' like  function_Name : function(){} .

Comment: You can't define a function like `function_Name : function(){}`. It needs to be `function function_Name(){}` or `var function_Name = function(){}`

Comment: You mean  `var anyFunctionName = function(){}` and `function(){}`

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn and this http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/different-ways-of-defining-functions-in-javascript-this-is-madness/

Comment: Please take note that in standard international English questions are followed by a question mark (with no intervening space). Sentences start with a capital letter. Code in your question should be surrounded by backticks to make it formatted properly. You need to apply the same attention to detail in writing your question as I know you apply in your programming work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be useful

**Named function**

```
function someName(){
 //rest of code
}
```

can be called by `someName()`;

**Function expression**

```
var someName = function(){}
```

can be called by `someName()`

**IIFE**

```
(function(someParam){
 //rest of code
}(params))
```

`IIFE` can also can also written in this way

```
+function(someParam){
//rest of code
}(someParam)
```

**Named function expression**

```
var someVar = function someFoo(){};
```

this is called by `someVar()` . `someFoo` is only accessible inside itself

**Arrow function**(aka fat arrow)

```
var someVar= (param1, param2) => {return somereturn}
```

**Function constructor**

```
var adder = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');
```

Beside this you can also take a look at `call` & `apply`

Comment: I think you left an extra `}` in your example of IIFE

Comment: @GibboK thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have edited it

Comment: Why would he look at `call` and `apply`? They are ways to invoke functions, not define them, which is what his question was about.

Answer (score -1):

There is no "best" way to define a function, it depends on your needs. For example if you have a function that validates something it makes sense to put it into a variable like Pugazh said:

```
var foo = function(){
  if (/*some condition*/) {
    //do something...;
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
```

And then use it like `alert(foo());` and it will execute the function and return the value (true or false).
Sometimes you want a named function you can call with options like:

```
function SaveData(data) {
    //Code to save something
}
```

And then call it like `SaveData("Hello World");`

And sometimes you just add a function without a name that is executed as a callback (e.g. in jquery) or when you perform a specific action but you define it at the event and not as a named function.

All types of functions have their use cases.